# Jupyter ceil quit from looping input

Tags: python, input, jupyter, eoferror

I am writing answer to this exercise:

> Write a Python program that repeatedly reads lines from standard input
>   until an EOFError is raised, and then outputs those lines in reverse order
>   (a user can indicate end of input by typing ctrl-D).

The code I write is following:

```
data = []
try:
    while True:
        data.append(input())

except EOFError:
    for i in range(len(data)-1,-1,-1):
        print(data[i])
```

If I run script in pycharm(`ctrl + shift + F10`), I can use `ctrl + D` to quit. **However, When I run it in a jupyter ceil, I have no idea how to quit this looping without shutdown the whole kernel!**

Can anyone explain this to me? Should I revised the code by some means?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra catch for Keyboard interrupt and send an Interrupt via Kernel->Interrupt

```py
data = []
try:
    while True:
        data.append(input())

except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
    for i in range(len(data)-1,-1,-1):
        print(data[i])
```

Comment: How did you do a keyboard interrupt? I use `I` and `ctrl + c` and did not interrupt the ceil

Comment: It's on the Menu bar. Kernel->Interrupt